# How to add a header to an ACM article template

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, acm, acmart

I need to add a header to the first page only on an ACM article template (see the red text on the top  of the included image).
This is an example code. Plz. can you help me add a header even if through workarounds. The header is necessary.

```
    \documentclass[manuscript,screen,review]{acmart}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \providecommand\BibTeX{{%
    \normalfont B\kern-0.5em{\scshape i\kern-0.25em b}\kern-0.8em\TeX}}}
\setcopyright{acmcopyright}
\copyrightyear{2018}
\acmYear{2018}
\acmDOI{XXXXXXX.XXXXXXX}
\acmConference[Conference acronym 'XX]{Make sure to enter the correct
  conference title from your rights confirmation emai}{June 03--05,
  2018}{Woodstock, NY}

\acmBooktitle{Woodstock '18: ACM Symposium on Neural Gaze Detection,
 June 03--05, 2018, Woodstock, NY} 
\acmPrice{15.00}
\acmISBN{978-1-4503-XXXX-X/18/06}

\begin{document}

\title{The Name of the Title is Hope}

\author{Ben Trovato}
\authornote{Both authors contributed equally to this research.}
\email{trovato@corporation.com}
\orcid{1234-5678-9012}
\author{G.K.M. Tobin}
\authornotemark[1]
\email{webmaster@marysville-ohio.com}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{Institute for Clarity in Documentation}
  \streetaddress{P.O. Box 1212}
  \city{Dublin}
  \state{Ohio}
  \country{USA}
  \postcode{43017-6221}
}

\renewcommand{\shortauthors}{Trovato and Tobin, et al.}

\begin{abstract}
  A clear and well-documented \LaTeX\ document is presented as an
  article formatted for publication by ACM in a conference proceedings
  or journal publication. Based on the ``acmart'' document class, this
  article presents and explains many of the common variations, as well
  as many of the formatting elements an author may use in the
  preparation of the documentation of their work.
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
ACM's consolidated article template, introduced in 2017.

\end{document}
```

Here is the image showing in the first line where I need the header to be placed.
[image]